# JS problem with the month of February in non-leap months

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a simple calendar, but i have a problem with all non-leap fever months.

If you click on next until February 2023, March is shown, if you advance until 2024 (which is a leap), everything works, how can I solve?

```js
let nav = 0;

let test = () => {
  const dt = new Date();
  dt.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + nav);
  const day = dt.getDate();
  const month = dt.getMonth();
  const year = dt.getFullYear();
  const monthName = `${dt.toLocaleDateString("en", { month: "long" })} ${year}`;
  
  document.getElementById('feedBack').innerHTML = 'Nav: ' + nav + ' - Day: ' + 1 + ' - Month: ' + month + ' ( <b>' + monthName + '</b> ) - Year: ' + year;
}

test();
```

```css
#feedBack {margin-top:10px}
```

```html
<button onclick="nav--;test()">Prev</button>
<button onclick="nav=0;test();">Current</button>
<button onclick="nav++;test();">Next</button>

<div id="feedBack"></div>
```

Comment: I typically try to avoid simply recommending packages..however [momentjs](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is a fairly well established javascript library that can [help solve this problem](https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/05-query/09-is-leap-year/).

Comment: Don't use momentjs, see https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/ you better off using something like day.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wait for two days the problem will be solved hehe (today is 29/06, you are iterating over, 29/07, 29/08, etc.).

Or you could change day of the month object before incrementing the month.

```js
let nav = 0;

let test = () => {
  const dt = new Date();
  dt.setDate(1); // this will move to the first day of the current month
  dt.setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + nav);
  const month = dt.getMonth();
  const year = dt.getFullYear();
  const monthName = `${dt.toLocaleDateString("en", { month: "long" })} ${year}`;
  
  document.getElementById('feedBack').innerHTML = 'Nav: ' + nav + ' - Day: ' + 1 + ' - Month: ' + month + ' ( <b>' + monthName + '</b> ) - Year: ' + year;
}

test();
```

```css
#feedBack {margin-top:10px}
```

```html
<button onclick="nav--;test()">Prev</button>
<button onclick="nav=0;test();">Current</button>
<button onclick="nav++;test();">Next</button>

<div id="feedBack"></div>
```

Comment: I was almost there :) I understood that the problem was what you say, but I didn't understand how to fix it, thanks a lot for the tip ;)

Comment: I was lucky on this you were indeed very close. And I appreciate when a question include a functional code snippet :)